# Plotting with "Around"

Tags: plotting, around

I have a number with certain uncertainty

```
a1 = Around[1, 0.1]
```

I try to plot  a function  with this number

```
Plot[a1*x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

However nothing happened.

I was looking for something similar to this (the colour is not necessary):

```
a = Plot[1.1*x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
b = Plot[1*x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black];
c = Plot[0.9*x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[a, b, c]
```

[image]

**Question 1**

There is some way to make that the first plot appears? Or there is some more efficient method than plotting three times?

**Question 2**

If I have `a1=Around[1,0.1]` how can I get the Maximum value of a1? In this case is clear that is 1.1, however I have to obtain this value "manually"

Comment: For question 2: `Plus @@ Thread@ a1[{"Value", "Uncertainty"}]` or `a1["Value"] + a1["Uncertainty"]` will give you the value + the uncertainty. That, of course, may not be the maximum value of `a1` if the uncertainty is e.g. a standard deviation, but that's up to you to interpret. You may also be interested in other properties that you can extract from `Around` objects (see the details section of its docs).

Comment: Oh thank you, that was the solution for the question 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to get the plot programmatically:

```
a1 = Around[1, -0.1];
Plot[
  Evaluate@{a1["Value"] x, Thread[a1["Interval"] x, Interval]},
  {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Red}
]
```

[image: plot with three lines]

---

For question 2, either one of the following will give you the value + the uncertainty:

```
Plus @@ Thread@ a1[{"Value", "Uncertainty"}] 
a1["Value"] + a1["Uncertainty"]
```

That, of course, may not be the maximum value of a1 if the uncertainty is e.g. a standard deviation, but that's up to you to interpret. You may also be interested in other properties that you can extract from [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) objects (see the details section of its docs).